# R function to calculate moving average with varying number of measurements for a given time point

Tags: r, zoo, moving-average, rolling-average

For each time point in my data frame, I have any where from 2 to 4 measurements. I want to calculate the moving average, so that for a given time point I have one value that is the average of all measurements for that time point + the time point before and the time point after.

```
cellcounts <-c(80, 188, 206, 162, 106,  90,  85, 109,  87,  94,  86, 196, 132, 135,  84, 122,  67,  88,  81, 121,   9,  93, 117, 91, 108, 103, 119, 100,  18,  98,  93, 119, 140, 160, 101,  82, 111, 103,  28,  72, 144,  85,   1)
time <-c(-2.7, -2.8, -2.9, -3.0, -3.1, -3.2, -3.3, -3.4, -3.5, -3.6, -2.7, -2.8, -2.9, -3.0, -3.1, -3.2, -3.3, -3.4, -3.5, -3.6, -3.9, -3.0, -3.1, -3.2, -3.3, -3.4, -3.5, -3.7, -2.5, -2.6, -2.9, -3.0, -3.2, -3.3, -3.4, -3.5, -3.7, -3.8, -2.5, -2.6, -3.7, -3.8, -3.9)
df <- data.frame(cellcounts, time)
df <- df[order(df$time),]
df
zoo::rollapply(df, width = 3, FUN = mean, align = "center", fill = NA)
```

Comment: Can you give the first few lines of the expected results. Its not explicitly clear what you want. eg do you want `mean(c(allcurrent points,all previous, all next)`? `mean(current point) +  mean(previous) + mean(next points)`, `mean(c(mean(current), previous[1], next[1]))` .. Notice how each of these will be different. So you need to explicitly elaborate as to what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R:

```
with(
  rle(df$time),
  {
    cs_x <- c(NA, 1L, cs_x <- cumsum(lengths) + 1L, NA)
    cs_y <- c(0, cumsum(df$cellcounts))
    data.frame(
      time = values,
      av_cellcounts = (cs_y[cs_x[-(1:3)]] - cs_y[cs_x[1:(length(cs_x) - 3L)]])/
        (cs_x[-(1:3)] - cs_x[1:(length(cs_x) - 3L)])
    )
  }
)
#>    time av_cellcounts
#> 1  -3.9            NA
#> 2  -3.8      79.00000
#> 3  -3.7     108.28571
#> 4  -3.6     104.33333
#> 5  -3.5      98.50000
#> 6  -3.4      99.16667
#> 7  -3.3     105.33333
#> 8  -3.2     106.36364
#> 9  -3.1     114.45455
#> 10 -3.0     124.70000
#> 11 -2.9     147.11111
#> 12 -2.8     140.14286
#> 13 -2.7     120.00000
#> 14 -2.6      63.66667
#> 15 -2.5            NA
```

Or, averaging only 2 time steps at the endpoints:

```
with(
  rle(df$time),
  {
    cs_x <- c(1L, 1L, cs_x <- cumsum(lengths) + 1L, cs_x[length(cs_x)])
    cs_y <- c(0, cumsum(df$cellcounts))
    data.frame(
      time = values,
      av_cellcounts = (cs_y[cs_x[-(1:3)]] - cs_y[cs_x[1:(length(cs_x) - 3L)]])/
        (cs_x[-(1:3)] - cs_x[1:(length(cs_x) - 3L)])
    )
  }
)
#>    time av_cellcounts
#> 1  -3.9      49.50000
#> 2  -3.8      79.00000
#> 3  -3.7     108.28571
#> 4  -3.6     104.33333
#> 5  -3.5      98.50000
#> 6  -3.4      99.16667
#> 7  -3.3     105.33333
#> 8  -3.2     106.36364
#> 9  -3.1     114.45455
#> 10 -3.0     124.70000
#> 11 -2.9     147.11111
#> 12 -2.8     140.14286
#> 13 -2.7     120.00000
#> 14 -2.6      63.66667
#> 15 -2.5      54.00000
```

Comment: thank you this is exactly what I needed! And you read my mind in needing to average only 2 for the time points at the end.

Comment: Beautiful and well vectorized solution

Answer (score 1):

The question did not specify what the result should be so we will assume the desired result is a rolling mean vector with the same number of elements as rows in the input `df`.  (2) and (3) compress and decompress the data so if a compressed version is wanted then just omit the `rep.int` (i.e. last) step in either of those two.

Note that we can't simply compress the data and use `rollapply` since the different runs are of different lengths.  These solutions take that into account.  They all use rollapply but take different approaches to using it.

(2) seems particularly short in terms of lines of code.

**1) list of offsets** The `width` argument to `rollapply` can be a list of vectors representing offsets to use so create that list, `offsets`, and then run `rollapply`.

We assume that the prior time is current time -0.1 and the next time is current time + 0.1 .

We convert to integer times to avoid floating point imprecision.  `before` is the number of positions back to start and `after` is the number forward to end at.

```
library(zoo)

itime <- as.integer(10 * df$time + 1e-5) # integer time
seqno <- seq_along(itime)
before <- match(itime - 1L, itime, nomatch = seqno) - seqno
after <- findInterval(itime + 1L, itime) - seqno
offsets <- Map(seq, before, after)

means <- rollapply(df$cellcounts, offsets, mean)
```

**2) compress/decompress**  Take sums and lengths over same time runs, perform `rollapply` on each and divide.  Then decompress using `rep.int` .

```
roll <- function(x) rollapply(x, 3, sum, partial = TRUE)

means2 <- df |>
  aggregate(cbind(cellcounts, lens = 1) ~ time, data = _, sum) |>
  with((roll(cellcounts) / roll(lens)) |> rep.int(lens))
```

**3) weighted.mean** Similar to (2) but we combine the means rather than the sums by using `weighted.mean`.

```
wm <- function(x, m = rbind(x)) weighted.mean(m[, 1], m[, 2])

means3 <- df |>
 with(data.frame(means = tapply(cellcounts, time, mean),
                 lens = tapply(cellcounts, time, length))) |>
 transform(means = rollapply(cbind(means, lens), 3, wm, partial = TRUE,
   by.column = FALSE)) |>
 with(rep.int(means, lens))
```

**4) wide form**  This adds sequence numbers, `seqno`, to each consecutive equal time in a run (1 for first row in a run, 2 for the next and so on) and then uses `read.zoo` to convert to wide form.  We then use `rollapply` on that producing a condensed form of the answer and as above use `rep.int` to expand that out to the final result.

```
means4 <- df |>
  transform(seqno = ave(time, time, FUN = seq_along)) |>
  read.zoo(index = "time", split = "seqno") |>
  rollapply(3, mean, na.rm = TRUE, partial = TRUE, by.column = FALSE) |>
  rep.int(rle(df$time)$lengths)
```

### Checking

```
identical(means, means2)
## [1] TRUE

identical(means, means3)
## [1] TRUE

identical(means, means4)
## [1] TRUE
```

Thus all four give the same answer which is

```
means
##  [1]  49.50000  49.50000  79.00000  79.00000 108.28571 108.28571 108.28571
##  [8] 104.33333 104.33333  98.50000  98.50000  98.50000  98.50000  99.16667
## [15]  99.16667  99.16667  99.16667 105.33333 105.33333 105.33333 105.33333
## [22] 106.36364 106.36364 106.36364 106.36364 114.45455 114.45455 114.45455
## [29] 124.70000 124.70000 124.70000 124.70000 147.11111 147.11111 147.11111
## [36] 140.14286 140.14286 120.00000 120.00000  63.66667  63.66667  54.00000
## [43]  54.00000
```

Comment: thank you for the very detailed answer. this is a very great approach, however for this problem I wanted the computed average to give one value for a given time point (e.g. one value for -2.5 time point, not two). I could have made this clearer in my question.

Comment: The answer does address this in the first paragraph where it says: *if a compressed version is wanted then just omit the `rep.int` (i.e. last) step* .  For example, (2) becomes `means2 <- df |> aggregate(cbind(cellcounts, lens = 1) ~ time, data = _, sum) |> with((roll(cellcounts) / roll(lens)))`  This applies to (2), (3) and (4) all of which produce that form and then use `rep.int` to expand it.   Note that with this change those alternatives involve even less code.   For (1) compress it using `tapply(means, df$time, unique)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

## Base R

Use `tapply`to compute the means by time, then compute the rolling means.

```r
x <- with(df, tapply(cellcounts, time, mean)) |>
  zoo::rollapply(width = 3, FUN = mean, align = "center", fill = NA)

## make a data.frame from the result above
df1 <- data.frame(time = as.numeric(names(x)), cellmeans = x)
df1
#>      time cellmeans
#> -3.9 -3.9        NA
#> -3.8 -3.8  72.44444
#> -3.7 -3.7 106.61111
#> -3.6 -3.6 106.02778
#> -3.5 -3.5 100.00000
#> -3.4 -3.4  99.16667
#> -3.3 -3.3 105.33333
#> -3.2 -3.2 106.02778
#> -3.1 -3.1 113.44444
#> -3   -3.0 124.41667
#> -2.9 -2.9 154.30556
#> -2.8 -2.8 139.55556
#> -2.7 -2.7 120.00000
#> -2.6 -2.6  63.66667
#> -2.5 -2.5        NA

# another way of creating a results df
df2 <- x |> as.data.frame()
df2$time <- x |> names() |> as.numeric()
df2
#>              x time
#> -3.9        NA -3.9
#> -3.8  72.44444 -3.8
#> -3.7 106.61111 -3.7
#> -3.6 106.02778 -3.6
#> -3.5 100.00000 -3.5
#> -3.4  99.16667 -3.4
#> -3.3 105.33333 -3.3
#> -3.2 106.02778 -3.2
#> -3.1 113.44444 -3.1
#> -3   124.41667 -3.0
#> -2.9 154.30556 -2.9
#> -2.8 139.55556 -2.8
#> -2.7 120.00000 -2.7
#> -2.6  63.66667 -2.6
#> -2.5        NA -2.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

And with `aggregate`.

```r
df3 <- aggregate(cellcounts ~ time, df, mean)
df3$cellcounts <- zoo::rollapply(df3$cellcounts, width = 3, FUN = mean, align = "center", fill = NA)
df3
#>    time cellcounts
#> 1  -3.9         NA
#> 2  -3.8   72.44444
#> 3  -3.7  106.61111
#> 4  -3.6  106.02778
#> 5  -3.5  100.00000
#> 6  -3.4   99.16667
#> 7  -3.3  105.33333
#> 8  -3.2  106.02778
#> 9  -3.1  113.44444
#> 10 -3.0  124.41667
#> 11 -2.9  154.30556
#> 12 -2.8  139.55556
#> 13 -2.7  120.00000
#> 14 -2.6   63.66667
#> 15 -2.5         NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Package `dplyr`

Use `summarise`to compute the means grouped by time, then compute the rolling means.

```r
suppressPackageStartupMessages(
  library(dplyr)
)

df %>%
  group_by(time) %>%
  summarise(cellmeans = mean(cellcounts, .groups = "drop")) %>%
  mutate(cellmeans = zoo::rollapply(cellmeans, width = 3, FUN = mean, align = "center", fill = NA))
#> # A tibble: 15 × 2
#>     time cellmeans
#>    <dbl>     <dbl>
#>  1  -3.9      NA  
#>  2  -3.8      72.4
#>  3  -3.7     107. 
#>  4  -3.6     106. 
#>  5  -3.5     100  
#>  6  -3.4      99.2
#>  7  -3.3     105. 
#>  8  -3.2     106. 
#>  9  -3.1     113. 
#> 10  -3       124. 
#> 11  -2.9     154. 
#> 12  -2.8     140. 
#> 13  -2.7     120  
#> 14  -2.6      63.7
#> 15  -2.5      NA
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-20 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: this is a very reasonable approach and one i considered, however for this problem I didn't want the computed average to be an average of averages. I should have specified this in my original question.

Answer (score 0):

The [zoo-FAQ](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zoo/vignettes/zoo-faq.pdf)
recomends de-duplicating a time-series with multiple measures per time.

Here is an example that `aggregate()`s the duplicated measures with `mean()`
and applies the rolling average afterward.

```r
library(zoo)

z <- zoo(cellcounts, time)
#> Warning in zoo(cellcounts, time): some methods for "zoo" objects do not work if
#> the index entries in 'order.by' are not unique
z <- aggregate(z, identity, mean)

rollapply(
  z,
  width = 3,
  FUN = mean,
  align = "center",
  # partial = TRUE, # uncomment to include means for first and last entries
  fill = NA
)
#>      -3.9      -3.8      -3.7      -3.6      -3.5      -3.4      -3.3      -3.2 
#>        NA  72.44444 106.61111 106.02778 100.00000  99.16667 105.33333 106.02778 
#>      -3.1        -3      -2.9      -2.8      -2.7      -2.6      -2.5 
#> 113.44444 124.41667 154.30556 139.55556 120.00000  63.66667        NA
```

Comment: this is a very reasonable approach and one i considered, however for this problem I didn't want the computed average to be an average of averages. I should have specified this in my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

Using dplyr and slider

We use `consecutive_id` to create an increasing integer ID, ensuring that adjacent time points are always separated by a distance of 1.

We then pass that ID to `slide_index_mean` which takes duplicate time points into account by calculating means for the shared time intervals.

```
library(dplyr)
library(slider)
df %>%
  mutate(time_id = consecutive_id(time)) %>%
  mutate(mean = slide_index_mean(cellcounts, i = time_id, before = 1, after = 1)) %>%
  distinct(time_id, .keep_all = TRUE) %>%
  select(time, mean)

   time    mean
1  -3.9  49.500
2  -3.8  79.000
3  -3.7 108.286
4  -3.6 104.333
5  -3.5  98.500
6  -3.4  99.167
7  -3.3 105.333
8  -3.2 106.364
9  -3.1 114.455
10 -3.0 124.700
11 -2.9 147.111
12 -2.8 140.143
13 -2.7 120.000
14 -2.6  63.667
15 -2.5  54.000
```

Comment: this is a very great approach, however for this problem I wanted the computed average to give one value for a given time point (e.g. one value for -2.5 time point, not two). I should have specified this in my question.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated my answer to reflect this.